# How to log recently files accessed in Linux for data mining

Tags: filesystems

How to get the list of files accessed in linux based on certain folde  . lets say we have a folder name /data .. i want to know which files accessed when . One option is to run

```
 # find . -atime xyz  ..
```

is there any better way to do this ? i mean does kernel store somewhere the log of accessed files ?

Comment: What is your issue with running that `find` command?  The kernel of a generic Unix system does not store the last accessed timestamps of files.

Comment: Hello, Welcome on SE UNix&Linux please take the time to read the [tour]. If you have a question the best way to ask is to explain it in 3 steps: 1- your goal (the bigger picture, not just details ) 2- what you've tried 3- What is not working as expected.

Comment: Its file-system's inode table where all these information of files are saved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use inotify

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

inotify-tools

here's an an example

```
 inotifywait -m /etc



/etc/ OPEN hosts
/etc/ ACCESS hosts
/etc/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE hosts
/etc/ OPEN hosts
/etc/ ACCESS hosts
/etc/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE hosts
/etc/ OPEN passwd
/etc/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE passwd
/etc/ OPEN passwd
/etc/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE passwd
/etc/ OPEN hosts
/etc/ ACCESS hosts
/etc/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE hosts
/etc/ OPEN passwd
/etc/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE passwd
```